# How can I use the r(for raw data)for strings in Python in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I was working on a bot, which should do something and play an mp3 after it. Now I need to write a function, because I use it often. I need to give Python a Path to find the mp3 file and must use Backslashes normally for a Path, but when I just give a Path(with Backslashes), Python see it as a command, like \n(new line) or something else. There must be a r `print(r'PATH')` or `print('PATH', 'r')` and I have problems to put the r in a function. I have tried all of the possibilitys, that I know, but nothing worked:

```
from pygame import mixer  


def musicplayer(r, pfad):
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(pfad)
    mixer.music.play()
musicplayer('r', 'D:\Tools\mine.mp3')
Error: TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

def musicplayer(pfad, r='r'):
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(pfad, r)
    mixer.music.play()
musicplayer('D:\Tools\mine.mp3')
Error: TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Thanks for help and give a feedback for how good I asked my question

Comment: Why don't you do it like you say: `r'D:\Tools\mine.mp3'`? Why do you need to "put it in a function"? Your string literal is either raw or not. You can't give later commands of how to process it. It is only raw at point of definition.

Comment: See the documentation for [**`mixer.music.load`**](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load). You are inventing parameters for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't represent a syntactic element with a variable.  It looks as if you want something akin to

```
loop_thing = "for"

loop_thing item in my_list:
    ...
```

You can't modify a string constant that way.  Simply use

```
r'D:\Tools\mine.mp3'
```

There's no need to differentiate the cases -- or do you have an application you haven't shown us?